# A led mystery ? how to connect?

Tags: led, led-strip, rgb

We have ordered from a supplier some high power leds - `20W RGB`.
They dont have any data sheet , and so we where thinking that we would try and find quickly how to connect them .

Everything we tried failed, we even checked a few of them, and nothing worked.

Well, what happens is that sometimes it flashes for a second and then never turn on again, and sometimes we see a very low green light from it .

We have the right voltage and current supply for it (600mA,32V) , but i guess we still had not guess the right configuration.

Please check this image :
[image]

We tried also to switch the vcc/gnd, we also tried to ground the body and then give ground to one of the `rgb` pins, but nothing ...

I guess it works in low, so that you give it a vcc, then you ground the r/g/b to get the right color .

What are we missing here ?

Comment: @Curnlious: You close with "What are we missing here?". So you are missing a datasheet and current limiting. Buying such components without a datasheet is utterly useless, for the reasons you are currently experiencing.

Comment: Throw them away and buy LEDs with a datasheet.

Comment: Congratulations - you've just blown out your LEDs. You applied 32 volts across a string of bare LEDs, and the voltage was just a tad high. The LEDs drew much more than 600 mA, and that's why you got a brief flash followed by nothing. And in fact, if 20 w is the spec for the LED as a whole, you should be limiting your current to 200 mA per string. Either use a supply with adjustable current limiting (and set the limit by shorting the output), or use a higher-voltage supply and provide a proper current limiting resistor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you might have some luck, googling 20W RGB turns up stuff that looks mostly like yours; so go through those links and try to find some info or call/email the sellers: google.com/search?q=20W+RGB&tbm=isch

And I don't think the pinout is much of an issue.

[image]

On the other hand you might need [different voltages](http://www.aliexpress.com/store/product/High-Power-20W-RGB-LED-Light-Bulb-Lamp-Bead-Chip-Red-Green-Blue/136394_1761167023.html) for each color, [same here](http://www.dx.com/p/20w-integrated-rgb-led-light-bulb-6-series-and-3-in-parallel-158332), [here](http://www.ebay.com/itm/20W-RGB-High-Power-LED-Panel-20-Watt-Lamp-Light-/160930241717), or [here](http://www.aliexpress.com/item/free-shiping-30pcs-20W-RGB-LED-Bead-Round-Base-Epstar-LED-Chips-4Pins-30-80lm-Red/1498204913.html).

It seems like your voltage and current spec don't match anything visually similar found in that search; those are generally 300-350mA per chain/color and 18-20V for G & B but only 10-15V for R.

---

In response to your questions in the comments: In all likelihood, those are simply DC voltages. Each of the three color chains is a series of 6 (it seems) LEDs. These three chains are connected as in the diagram below:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fquj7q.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: when you say between (10-15v) , and anywhere where they say it, do they mean that my pwm duty cycle has to change to output this voltages? or do i have to switch the MOSFET in that one voltage (for example 12v) ?

Comment: something is wrong with the digram and your answer, if the r g and b gets different voltages, how is this going with your draw? you have in there only one plus that goes into the led, then 3 minuses..

Comment: @Curnelious: I've expanded my answer to reply to your new questions/comments.